# How to style SegmentedButtons from react-native-paper library?

Tags: react-native, react-native-paper

I want to custom style the `SegmentedButtons` from `react-native-paper` library.

I want to either remove the border or make them square shaped. By default the `SegmentedButtons` come with rounded corners.

As a solution I tried styling the `SegmentedButtons` with `StyleSheet` and also inline style. I tried following properties:

```js
{ 
  borderRadius: 0,
  borderWidth: 0
}
```

None of them worked.

Answer (score 3):

You can style each button individually with the `style` prop, in order to remove the rounded corners. Then override the theme with `roundness: 0` so that you fix the ripple effect styles.

```js
<SegmentedButtons
  value={value}
  onValueChange={setValue}
  density="medium"
  theme={{ roundness: 0 }}
  buttons={[
    {
      value: "walk",
      label: "Walking",
      style: {
        borderRadius: 0,
      },
    },
    {
      value: "train",
      label: "Transit",
      style: {
        borderRadius: 0,
      },
    },
    {
      value: "drive",
      label: "Driving",
      style: {
        borderRadius: 0,
      },
    },
  ]}
/>;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the theme prop instead:

```
  <SegmentedButtons
     value={value}
     onValueChange={setValue}
     buttons={[
       {
         value: "walk",
         label: "Today",
       },
       {
         value: "train",
         label: "Future",
       },
     ]}
     theme={{ roundness: 2 }}
  />
```